# How to spatial join 2 point layers in postgres/postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I was trying to join pole(point) and customer(point) layers using spatial join. I created a 20 meter buffer around pole then wrote below query.It takes too much time

```
SELECT  distinct h.gid, d.polecode FROM  
buildings as h  left join   
pole_buffer_20 as d
on
ST_Intersects(d.the_geom,h.the_geom)
```

Help me with a query without using buffering

Answer (score 1):

For checking if points are contained in polygons you should use the the function  [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html), which is faster:

```
SELECT  distinct h.gid, d.polecode FROM  
buildings as h  left join   
pole_buffer_20 as d
on
ST_DWithin(d.the_geom,h.the_geom, 0);
```

ST_DWithin accepts a distance parameter too, so, depending of your needs, you could avoid the step with the buffer table and use directly you original table:

```
SELECT  distinct h.gid, d.polecode FROM  
buildings as h  left join   
pole as d
on
ST_DWithin(d.the_geom,h.the_geom, 20);
```

The distance parameter is in unit of the geometry. If you want a search radius of 20 meters, you need geometries which are expressed in meter (or use geography type)

Comment: Thanks You @Tomm. Do you have any idea how NNjoin plugin has been written for spatial joins in QIS. I am looking for exact query of NNjoin.

Comment: I don't know this plugin, sorry

Comment: Anyone can help me with NNjoin plugin

Comment: Your question about the NNJoin plugin is off topic here. You should either accept the answer or comment and explain what is wrong. For questions about Qgis plugins you should open another topic

Comment: Let me continue the present topic. Is it possible to do a spatial join without giving any radius between two non intersecting or non overlapping layers.

Comment: If you are interested in the implementation of the NNJoin plugin, you can visit http://arken.umb.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/NNJoin/ for an overview of the implementation, and https://github.com/havatv/qgisnnjoinplugin for the code (Python).